# C language: args in functions inside Main (). Unclear what they are

Tags: c, program-entry-point, args

I have been struggling to understand some pieces of this code. It asks to enter some strings, will count the vowels and display the result. It is some definitions that I don't understand, the mechanics I do.

In the definitions inside main(). I dont understand what for an argument this '(cad)' is in the entrada function. One line above it is defined an array of 3 pointers to char, namely char *cad[N] if I correctly believe. I would say my problem is everything in the Main function, how the arguments make sense inside the parentheses for the functions. After that I understand alright.

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<string.h>
# include<ctype.h>
# define N 3


// Function Prototypes

void salida(char *[], int*);
void entrada(char *[]);
int vocales(char *);

int main ()
{
    char *cad[N];  // declaring an array of 3 pointers to char
    int j, voc[N]; // declaring ints and an array of ints
    entrada (cad);// Function to read in strings of characters. 
    // count how many vowels per line
    for (j = 0; j<N; j++)
    voc[j] = vocales(cad[j]); // it gets the string and sends it to function vocales to count how many vowels. Returns number to array voc[j]
    salida (cad, voc);
}

// Function to read N characters of a string
void entrada(char *cd[] ){
    char B[121]; // it just creates an array long enough to hold a line of text
    int j, tam;

    printf("Enter %d strings of text\n", N );

    for (j= 0; j < N; j++){
        printf ("Cadena[%d]:", j + 1);
        gets(B);
        tam = (strlen(B)+1)* sizeof(char); // it counts the number of characters in one line
        cd[j] = (char *)malloc (tam); // it allocates dynamically for every line and array index enough space to accommodate that line
        strcpy(cd[j], B); // copies the line entered into the array having above previously reserved enough space for that array index
    } // so here it has created 3 inputs for each array index and has filled them with the string. Next will be to get the vowels out of it

}

// Now counting the number of vowels in a line
int vocales(char *c){
    int k, j;

    for(j= k= 0; j<strlen(c); j++)
        switch (tolower (*(c+j)))
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
              k++;
              break;
        }
    return k;
}

// function to print the number of vowels that each line has
void salida(char *cd[], int *v)
{
    int j;

    puts ("\n\t Displaying strings together with the number of characters");
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        printf("Cadena[%d]: %s has %d vowels \n", j+1, cd[j], v[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) you could ask it what is the type of some name, e.g. `ptype cad` or `ptype salida`

Comment: You could consider using Linux, `gdb` works very well on it. But you should compile your source with warnings and debug information, e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cad` is an array of pointers.  It only has space for N pointers, not the actual string data.  The `entrada` function reads N strings of text.  For each of these it allocates some space with `malloc` and copies the string there.  `entrada` sets the corresponding pointer in `cad` (which it sees as `cd`) to point to the allocated buffer.

When you pass an array as an argument, you are not passing a copy.  Instead, the address of the first element is passed to the function.  This is how `entrada` can modify the pointers in `cad`.

Comment: thank you, I wrote the comments myself in the code, and clearly char *cad[N] is an array of pointers, but then, the plain 'cad', also? as it is in parentheses as an argument to the function entrada. I understand the function entrada it is the confusion that causes me seeing char *cad[N] as an array of pointers but also cad being that.

Comment: @iaintunderstand: `char *cad[N]` *is* nothing. It declares `cad` to be an array of pointers.

Comment: thank you, sorry for my problems with the syntax and declarations. I will remember this teaching.

Comment: `char *cad[N];` is a declaration.  The statement simply means "the name `cad` refers to an array of `char *`.  Basically, you made an array and called it `cad`.  From that point on you can use the name to refer to the array.  Same with variables: `int i;` means "make a space to hold an `int` and call it `i`".

Comment: Now another point that is a bit more tricky.  The name `cad` is visible in the _scope_ that it was declared in (so, in function `main`).  If you declare something also called `cad` in another function it will refer to a different thing entirely.  When you pass `cad` to `entrada`, `cd` is made to point to the same memory location as `cad`.

Comment: Thank you. As I continue with the reading of the code, somewhat a similar thing baffles me: at the main function, the vowels 'call' function has cad[j] as a parameter. But when I go to the vowels function the argument is a char pointer. not the array of pointers that was sent from entrada.

Comment: Function arguments are evaluated before being passed to the function.  So for `cad[j]` the subscript operator is applied first.  It evaluates to a single element of the `cad` array, which is just a `char *`.  This value is then passed to the function.